Water ingress through a pebble dashed external gable wall
enter image description hereI have a problem with water ingress in my house. The situation is located above the third floor in a bedroom below a window cill on a southwest facing pebble-dashed external wall. I have applied silicone sealant around all around the possible areas of abutment of the pebble-dashing to the window to no avail! Can anyone help with a possible solution please?

You really must provide pictures of both inside and outside.  Otherwise you will get suggestions base totally on guesses.

My guess, with or without pictures, is that there are some cracks in the exterior wall, somewhere above the window. The water is getting in there, running down the wall, and coming out into the room near the window. Or... there's a leak in the roof that's letting water run down the wall which is then coming out into the window. Water is insidious - it'll find a way in, then once in, it'll find a way out. The In/Out locations don't have to be anywhere near each other...

Hello Gentlemen, thank you for your comments duly noted. FYI the roof was retiled in 2022 and the high level pebble-dashing sometime before that because this upper area had ‘blown’ & fallen off. I have now attached 3 photographs, 1 exterior with 2 of the interior areas resultant damage below the windowsill. I guess the only way to really establish where the water is getting in, is to carry out a close up inspection  of the entire exterior area?
